# How to use the eivls operator with a nullable lambda parameter?

Tags: kotlin, operator-keyword, nullable

I have a function with a nullable lambda parameter defined as -

```
fun download_a_file(callback_after_download_is_complete: (() -> Any)? = null)
    {
        // ... do things ...
    }
```

The idea is that after the file is downloaded, whoever is calling the function can pass a lambda function to execute some code after the file is downloaded.

The parameter is null since someone may not wish to have a lambda post download.

So inside the `download_a_file function` I have this code -

```
if( callback_after_download_is_complete != null)
    callback_after_download_is_complete()
```

Which works, but isn't elegant. I'd rather use a elvis operator here, if I can. 
However I'm not finding any good references on how to call a nullable lambda parameter with the elvis operator. Can you do that? if so - how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice, you cannot call an anonymous nullable function directly:

> Reference has a nullable type '(() -> Any)?', use explicit
>   '?.invoke()' to make a function-like call instead

So all you have to do is use `invoke/0`:

```
fun download_a_file(callback_after_download_is_complete: (() -> Any)? = null) {
  callback_after_download_is_complete?.invoke()
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is that it's actually working on my code when I directly call the function.
But i'll use the invoke method and see what happens

Comment: Ah, I think it worked on my code when I directly called the function because it was within a null check. Seems the compiler is smart enough to pick that.